# django fabric set hosts for deployment

Tags: python, django, fabric

I want to deploy my code in localhost and my live version for this automation i used fabric. My basic fabric file look like:

```
 def localhost():
    "Use the local virtual server"
    env.hosts = ['127.0.0.1']
    env.user = 'user'
    env.path = '/var/www/html/{}'.format(env['project_name'])
    env.virtualhost_path = env.path

def webserver():
    "Use the actual webserver"
    env.hosts = ['www.example.com']
    env.user = 'username'
    env.path = '/var/www/html/{}'.format(env['project_name'])
    env.virtualhost_path = env.path

def setup():
require('hosts', provided_by=[localhost])
require('path')

sudo("apt-get update -y")
sudo("apt-get install git -y")
sudo("apt-get install postgresql libpq-dev python-dev python-pip -y")
sudo("apt-get install redis-server -y")
sudo("apt-get install nginx -y")

sudo('aptitude install -y python-setuptools')
sudo('apt-get install python-pip')
sudo('pip install virtualenv virtualenvwrapper')
```

For now i only want to deploy to my local machine. When I do this it gives me erro saying

```
The command 'setup' failed because the following required environment variable was not defined:
hosts

Try running the following command prior to this one, to fix the problem:
localhost
```

What does `provided_by=([localhost])` do in here. I guess it should provide the information like hosts and user in localhost.

Why I am getting this error ??
Need help

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why that doesn't work other than it's not mentioned in the docs as how host lists get constructed. Your options for setting the host value are:

1. Specify `env.hosts = ['127.0.0.1']` globally in your fabfile
2. Pass the host to fab: `fab -H 127.0.0.1 setup`
3. Call the localhost task: `fab localhost setup`
4. Use the @hosts decorator on your setup function

See http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.10/usage/execution.html#how-host-lists-are-constructed

Answer (score 0):

fabric.operations.require(*keys, **kwargs):

> Check for given keys in the shared environment dict and abort if not
>   found... The optional keyword argument **provided_by** may be a list of functions or function names or a single function or function name which the user should be able to execute in order to set the key or keys; it will be included in the error output if requirements are not met.

http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.10/api/core/operations.html?highlight=require#fabric.operations.require

That why you get the error message saying to run `localhost` first, then `setup`:

```
fab localhost setup
```